# Importing a CSV file through java and output is: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file like this through java into mysql db:

```
CODE  |SIZE
994445|15
994471|15
994472|11
994473|11
994474|18
994475|15
994476|15
```

In the DB, it should insert into STORAGE table with attributes: OUTLET_code and size. CODE is an Outlet Code and SIZE refers to the storage size in that outlet; there can be more than one storage but not with the same size. Thus, both attributes are the primary keys, having a composite primary key for the STORAGE table. There are 2,000+ rows in the CSV file and only 439 rows are successfully being imported to mysql database. Here are my tables:

[The first 439 rows enter but not the rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxmdZ.png)
[OUTLET_code is a foreign key from OUTLET table. But both attributes are the primary keys for STORAGE table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgkLv.jpg)

I dont get why the first 439 rows enter but not the rest. I'm using netbeans and this is my code for importing the file:

```
 public static String importFile(){           
    String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO CABINET VALUES (?,?)";
    String status;
    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\fullpathfilehere\\Cabinet.csv"), ','); Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();){
        PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        String[] rowData = null;

        int i = 0;
        while((rowData = reader.readNext()) != null){
            status = "Working";
            for (String data : rowData){
                pstmt.setString((i % 2) + 1, data);
                if (++i % 2 == 0)
                    pstmt.addBatch();// add batch
                if (i % 20 == 0)// insert when the batch size is 10
                   pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        status = "Completed";
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        status = "Error - " + e.getMessage();
    }

    return status;
}
```

I've been using code above for other files to import into the database like employees and they have been successful. But for this, the output I receive is:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sandapp`.`cabinet`, CONSTRAINT `fk_CABINET_OUTLET1` FOREIGN KEY (`OUTLET_code`) REFERENCES `outlet` (`code`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ServerPreparedStatement.java:652)
>       at logic.ImportCabinet.importFile(ImportCabinet.java:28)

If anyone can help the would be really appreciated :)

Comment: You've probably done this already, but did you inspect the file you're importing at line 439 for any non-integer values?

Comment: yes, i tried editing the values, deleting that row, and other to check but the it's always the same output and inserting stops at the same row number

Comment: Seems like OUTLET_code values, starting from line 439, are already loaded on table cabinet. Please, check if csv has repeated OUTLET_code values, or if table already has those values from line 439 and ahead.

Comment: I would truncate all the data in cabinet table for every test and the same problem occurs. I checked as well the csv file for any repeating (same code, same size) cells and there are none.